# WCF client application crashes when accessing service

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, console

I have created a wcf web service with access to ADO.net Entity Framework. Hosts on IIS and have console client. Everything works fine.. on my computer. When I send .exe file to another its just crashes and I cant figure out why.
Code of console app:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
Console.WriteLine(client.GetOrders().First().Date_Accepted.ToString());
client.Close();
Console.ReadLine();
```

My web.config file is default with no changes except of connection string.
Client app.config

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://93.77.254.167:9595/MyService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyServiceReference.IMyService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any Ideas why?

Comment: have you tried entering the wcf url in the browser of the client to see if it is reachable? And could you post the exception?

Comment: Define "crashes": e.g. the console application closes without messages,  or the whole computer needs to be rebooted,  or we get some cryptic exception message,  etc.    Also try to describe the behavior on alternate machine more precisely,  does it appear to time-out, does it "crashes" almost instantly...  Finaly,  it would be a good idea, for diagnostics purposes to split the multiple operations in the WriteLine statement over multiple lines, intertwined with "debug" writeline texts.

Comment: well Ill appreciate if you can check? Actualy client see the service is created and I think its means that its reacheable. There is no exception, just crash.

Comment: What happens when someone on this workstation opens  "http://93.77.254.167:9595/MyService.svc?wsdl" from a web browser?

Comment: They see the same that i see. XML Code

Comment: Good.  this confirm that they have basic connectivity to the webservice.
Any chance you produce a test version of the console app, which
a) split the GetOrders() from the First() and Date_Accepted, along with test of counts, non null and such in between
b) wrap the section in a try catch and print-out any exception that may be caught that way.
?

Comment: Definitely wrap the Console code in a try catch, and console.writeline the exception!

Comment: I got it :) I just send 2 files to client .exe and .exe.config and it worked. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap you code in a try catch block and you will see what goes wrong.

```
try
{
 MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
 Console.WriteLine(client.GetOrders().First().Date_Accepted.ToString());
 client.Close();
 Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```